# Customizer Appearance Issue

Tags: css, theme-customizer, server, previews

I am developing new WP theme and it's in the phase of beta testing. So, it has succesfully installed and it's working on some sites. But, now there is one problem on particular host server. (shared hosting), on any domain I use.
When I make changes in customizer there are occured and visible, but when I navigate in preview window to another page, for example: Sample page, changes made on front page are not registered but they are saved and shown on actual site link. When I do force refresh every change I made is shown properly.
It seems there is issue with server, because everything works fine on another server. (and on localhost also)
CSS is saved in special file using WP filesystem, maybe problem is with that, I don't know really.

Thanks in advance...

SK

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a server side caching issue.  Assuming the refresh you mention is to your browser, this would not necessarily fix the issue.

Shared hosting servers can have various tiers of server side caching and/or services like Cloudflare that can cause issues like you describe.  Without knowing the specifics of your hosting environment its hard to rule out or advise a fix.

I'd suggest giving your shared hosting support line a call and asking what caching might be running, and seeing if you can flush it our turn it off to rule it out as the problem.

Comment: Thanks, probably it was about server side caching caused with writing file. But, I couldn't develope theme further dealing with possible servers issues on some sites. Now I have removed these lines of code and change my way of storing css changes. I guess the standard way using wp_head could be more reliable and everything is going well.